# How to generate a jpeg image file from a given url variable in php

Tags: php

I have a image url which i assigned to a variable in php . I need to output and save the image in jpeg format how can i do this ? can anyone help me ?

Comment: Hi @PandaSurya, can you share what you tried?

Answer (score 0):

You can just use `file_get_contents`/`file_put_contents` to save the URL to a file:

```php
$url = 'https://pbs.twimg.com/media/D8PDAZmXsAAoe1T.jpg';
$filename = end(explode('/', $url));

file_put_contents(filename, file_get_contents($url));
```